# REST call with XQIB reports function send-request not available

Tags: javascript, xml, xquery

I have been trying simple REST call with XQIB. My attempt is only more simplified example (http://www.xqib.org/js/RESTCallCourses_source.html), but I can't get to run neither of them. I get the same error in both cases:

> MXQuery output the following error during compilation: Line 8, Column
>   12: err:XPST0017 Function named http-client:send-request with arity 1
>   not available

It must be something obvious, but I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>   
    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mxqueryjs/mxqueryjs.nocache.js"></script>
    <script type="application/xquery">
      declare namespace http-client = "http://expath.org/ns/http-client";

        for $x in http-client:send-request
          (
            <http-client:request href="http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xprazak2/xqib/samplefires.xml" method="get"/>
          )//*:street
        return
          insert node
            <p>{$x/*:street/data(.)}</p>
          as last into b:dom()//body     
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Will it work?</h1>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I even tried functions with different arities (http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/modules/expath/http-client), same error. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. It is definitely in the spec and I also tried with another XQuery processor, where this query works fine. I also tried using xqib and got the same error. Looks to me like the version used in there demo is more up-to-date than what is in the svn or you have to build it yourself with some special parameters.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I actually used the version available from the download section of their web page, which is 0.8.0. Version in svn repo is 0.6.0 (says readme file). Tried to build it anyway with Java 6, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Seems like a bug to me. It is definitely in the spec and I also tried with another XQuery processor, where this query works fine. I also tried using xqib and got the same error. Looks to me like the version used in there demo is more up-to-date than what is in the svn or you have to build it yourself with some special parameters